# Sonarqube custom rule for gradle dependency

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

Can sonar be used to create a custom rule to specify what version a gradle dependency should be?

Answer (score 0):

yup! You can use this rule template: "squid:S3417" aka "Track uses of disallowed dependencies" which allows you to define disallowed dependencies which will raise a sonar issue when found in sonar scans.